# How to build a simple shopping site? I'm novice and want to start from scratch

Tags: e-commerce

I'm barely a freelancer with knowledge of PHP and mysql. There's many website builders, people suggested, but I want to start from scratch.

I've basic idea how a shopping site works, but can't work with that. I want to know :

1. **how to setup the layers/structure,**
2. **what database system should I use,**
3. **how to implement security manners and handle security issues,**
4. **how to organize products/items,**
5. **which features to focus on mostly**  and
6. **what languages I should have least knowledge of ??**

Please bear in mind, I don't have any professional view, so please extend your answers/suggestion. I need help, please help.

I have knowledge in *DHTML, PHP, mysql, Oracle, jQuery, AngularJS and concept of CMS.*

Comment: E-commerce is a big thing to jump into.

Comment: don't mind the tag. it's just shopping site I'm talking.

Comment: I'm not clear on the distinction you're trying to make. If it's not e-commerce, why tag it as that?

Comment: Use shopify. Otherwise if you really want to learn and you have lots of time and nothing else to do - choose a php framework first. Learn that framework and the bootstrap css framework. Then you can start building. If you are not committed to PHP then learn Ruby and use Spree commerce framework.